# How to prevent Race Condition on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, race-condition

I have tried using transactions and also setting the transaction isolation level to serializable  but I still have the same issue.

Here is the way to reproduce my problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestRaceCondition
AS
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TABLE_A;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

    SELECT 1 ID INTO dbo.TABLE_A;
GO
```

Copy and paste the following code multiple times (I do 20 times) in 3 different sessions

```
EXEC dbo.TestRaceCondition;
GO
```

Then try to execute the 3 sessions at the same time.

This is the error I get in at least one of the sessions:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure dbo.TestRaceCondition, Line 46
> There is already an object named 'TABLE_A' in the database.

Hopefully someone can help me, thank you in advance!

I have tried using transactions

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestRaceCondition
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

    BEGIN TRAN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TABLE_A;

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

        SELECT 1 ID INTO dbo.TABLE_A;
    COMMIT TRAN
```

I expect running the procedure multiple times with no error.

Comment: Your code has proven that the race condition exists. It will randomly fail when a second execution starts and another one has created the table while the second one is waiting. Not sure why you would expect this to always work.

Comment: Having a SP that creates a permanent table, that is expected to run multiple times in parallel seems like a complete design flaw. Why are you dropping and creating a permanent table? There is probably a much better way of doing whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Poster clearly has an XY problem.

Comment: I cannot provide any details due to policy and this is not my code so I didn't design it, it was done like that for a reason though, there should be a better way but the code is too big and that table is being used in too many places, I would need to redesign all the code which implies too much effort, so there is no solution to this, is what you all are saying?

Comment: Well even if there is a solution, if you run the SP twice from 2 different connections, the second connection will delete all the data that the first connection added - surely that also is an issue? And even if it's a lot of work, the design is so bad it's just got to be done. Don't add more tech debt that will just bite the next person.

Comment: I imagine this only moves the problem elsewhere, but you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I'm surprised that a transaction didn't help.

Comment: @Charlieface - If the table doesn't exist then two transactions can both execute the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TABLE_A;` concurrently without blocking each other. One of them gets to the `SELECT 1 ID INTO dbo.TABLE_A;` and that blocks the other one. But then when the first transaction commits the table now exists and the second transaction is unblocked and throws that error

Comment: @MartinSmith Does `DROP` not take out a Sch-M lock rather than a Sch-S? Or is that only if the drop actually happens? Almost feels like there should be a `DROP WITH (UPDLOCK)` or something.

Comment: @DaleK as I said, I cannot provide the details but the logic works as it is and it wasn't created by me, in fact the error I mentioned doesn't occur too often (like once in a month), I'm not asking for a better way to do it, otherwise I'd need to provide the logic, actually I know a better way to do it but it requires a big effort, that will be my long term solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` only applies a `Sch-S` lock temporarily, and if the table needs to be dropped only then does it upgrade to a `Sch-M` lock.

While there are many ways to force an `Sch-M` lock, a more idiomatic way to do this might be to use [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which can create an arbitrary application-defined lock.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestRaceCondition
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = N'TestRaceCondition', @LockMode = 'Update';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TABLE_A;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

SELECT 1 ID INTO dbo.TABLE_A;

EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = N'TestRaceCondition';

COMMIT TRAN;
```

I would maintain though, that if you are dropping and re-creating the same table continuously then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: That is working thank you! I cannot provide details on why it was made like that but I know the design is wrong, I didn't do it though, this can be a short solution and redesign the procedure will be the long term solution. Thank you again